# Erro ao compilar o php 5.3.28 utilizando php-build

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, mint

Estou tentando instalar o PHP 5.3.28 utilizando o '[php-build](https://github.com/CHH/php-build)' no Linux Mint 16 (Ubuntu) mas ele não compila.

Estou utilizando o seguinte comando:

> php-build -i development 5.3.28 ~/local/php/5.3.28

Após resolver vários erros de falta de pacotes, está ocorrendo algum erro que não consigo identificar.

Veja o log completo:
http://pastebin.com/x5ZxNkQd

Preciso ter várias versões do PHP na mesma máquina, por isso estou utilizando o `php-build`

Como faço para corrigir esse problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Caso Geral

No Debian e em outras distros derivadas (Ubuntu, Mint, etc) você pode instalar todas as dependências de compilação de um determinado software usando o comando

> apt-get build-dep pacote

### Exemplo: PHP

para instalar as dependências de compilação para o [php](/questions/tagged/php), use o comando:

> apt-get build-dep php5

---

No seu caso, o log nos mostra que os pacotes ausentes são: `bison` e `libsqlite3` ambos serão instalados quando utilizar o comando acima

Comment: Olá obrigado pela dica, ao executar o comando aparceu a seguinte mensagem: "E: Você deve colocar algumas URIs 'source' em seu sources.list"

Comment: Isso quer dizer que suas fontes de pacotes não contem entradas para fontes de programas, você deve pesquisar na internet os links para os repositórios de fontes e adicionar em seu /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar, se conseguir resolver com essa dica eu marco como resposta. No mais valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: Após adicionar as linhas "deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all" e "deb-src http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all" e rodar novamente o comando apt-get build-dep php5. Eu consegui compilar facilmente com a ferramenta "php-build". Muito obrigado @hernandes! Agora vou utilizar o https://github.com/wilmoore/php-version para alternar facilmente entre as versões! Resposta aceita.

Comment: @LuizMartinsdeCarvalho apenas a segunda linha (deb-src) talvez bastasse, porem que bom que deu certo